# How to rollback deployments using ansible?

Tags: linux

I have copied 5 files from host machine to remote machine.
i have to remove files from remote machine the way stack works.

the file copied very first should be removed very last.

Answer (score 4):

Ansible doesn’t have rollback modes. You have to write a play that removes the files again.